# Boolean always returns false possibly due to values not increasing

Tags: java, boolean

This method, moreVowels, is intended to be able to count the amount of vowels and consonants in the String entered, and return true if the amount of vowels is greater than the amount of consonants. Sadly this code always returns false, and I cannot understand why. Here is the method stated:

```
public Boolean moreVowels()
    { vowelCount = 0;
      consonantCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
            {
            if ("AEOIUY".contains(word.substring(i,i++)) || "aeoiuy".contains(word.substring(i,i++)))
            {
                vowelCount++;
            }
            if ("BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ".contains(word.substring(i,i++)) || "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".contains(word.substring(i,i++)))
            {
                consonantCount++;
            }
        }
        if (vowelCount > consonantCount)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I believe it is always returning false due to the loop not actually increasing the counts, but I'm not quite sure why not. Thank you for reading, I'm sure the answer is something silly that I failed to recognize.

Comment: Change `word.substring(i,i++)` to `word.substring(i,i+1)`.

Comment: You can simplify the end of the method to `return vowelCount > consonantCount;`.

Comment: You can also change the return type to `boolean`, given that you'll never return null. I'd also strongly urge you to either put the opening brace at the end of `moreVowels()`, or put it on a line on its own.

Comment: in each for loop, there are totally 5 `i++`, so the value i is increased by 5 for each loop. As a result, you are not checking every character in the string. A better way to do so is using `String.charAt()` instead of `String.substring()`

Comment: `"AEOIUY".indexOf(word.charAt(i)) >= 0` is better than `"AEOIUY".contains(word.substring(i,i+1))`, since it is simpler, faster, and doesn't even allow the error you had.

Comment: The problem is that you used counter to subString, and misusing i++,
for your subString(i, i++), both of the value will be the same as i++ means increment after it executed, so you will always get empty String in return, more than that, your i now is now incremented, which result in skipping several char in the String or even finished the loop

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not use `substring(i,i++)`, but `substring(i,i+1)`. Otherwise, you'll increase `i`, making your code skip letters.

`"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".contains(word.substring(i,i+1))` looks like a mistake. It will cause `consonantCount` to increase in each loop for every lowercase letter.

If you're only dealing with words (no spaces etc.), then every word is either a consonant or a vowel, so you don't need the second `if`. You could get consonant count by subtracting `vowelCount` from `length`.

Furthermore, if you convert the i-th character to uppercase, you can omit the `|| "aeoiuy".contains(...)` part.

Comment: It's not always true.

Comment: It is true if and only if the character is lower case.

Comment: `word.substring(i,i++)` returns `""` (unless i is out of bounds) so `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".contains(word.substring(i,i++))` will never *return* something else than `true` (but it may also raise an exception)

Comment: `consonantCount` is only the same as `length - vowelCount` if you are absolutely 100% sure the text doesn't contains any spaces, special characters or accented letters. Since you don't have such a guarantee, your statement is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer and comment already show the problems with your code. I just want to add a possible stream based solution that can reduce the possibilty for errors by repacing the index based looping and local variables:

```
private static boolean moreVowels(String word)
{
    return word.chars()
               .mapToObj(c -> Character.toString((char) c).toUpperCase())
               .mapToInt(c -> "AEIOUY".contains(c) ? 1 : "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ".contains(c) ? -1 : 0)
               .sum() > 0;
}
```

You can apply the use of `toUpperCase()` to your own implementation as well to make the `if` statements a bit shorter (again avoiding possible errors).